# How to use 2 master files of vue JS in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

- I want to use View JS in the main admin panel and frontend in a Laravel project.
- But the major problem is how to manage the master file of the admin panel and frontend

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Just bundle them and output them separately within your `mix` config:

```
mix.js('resources/js/admin-panel.js', 'admin-panel.js')
   .js('resources/js/frontend.js', 'frontend.js')
```

And reference the appropriate file in your layouts (which I'm assuming differ), for example:

```
//layouts/admin.blade.php

<script src="{{ asset('admin-panel.js') }}"></script>
```

and for your frontend

```
//layouts/frontend.blade.php

<script src="{{ asset('frontend.js') }}"><
```